# Where is the command clean-css after its installation?

Tags: css, node.js

I downloaded nodes.js v0.10.15-linux-x86 and add it to path so that it is only usable by me. I installed clean-css@1.1.3. However, after the installation, I cannot find it anywhere.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css/-/clean-css-1.1.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css/-/clean-css-1.1.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-2.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-2.0.0.tgz
clean-css@1.1.3 node_modules/clean-css
└── commander@2.0.0
```

I looked at node/lib/node_modules/ directory, there is no such directory named as "clean-css".

Can you see what's wrong with the setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, npm will only install the module in a local `node_modules` folder. The idea is that each module, project you run can have isolated versions of its dependencies.

Try `npm install -g clean-css` (install globally) if you want to run it from the shell.

Comment: Yes, "-g" option works. Thanks! I can now find it at:"/home/Jaska/node-v0.10.15-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/clean-css" and "/home/Jaska/node-v0.10.15-linux-x86/bin".

Answer (score 1):

according to clean-css github page(https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css-cli), they split the versions into clean-css and clean-css-cli. so the command line version can be installed via "npm install clean-css-cli -g" and then it can be accessed from shell as "cleancss" again.

Comment: Somehow simple install isn't working, only global install. I am OSX Sierra.